# passing ‘const Link’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string GetAttribute(std::string)’ discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, ns-3

I'm getting an odd error with parts of the NS-3 API. Here is my error message:

```
error: passing ‘const ns3::TopologyReader::Link’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string ns3::TopologyReader::Link::GetAttribute(std::string)’ discards qualifiers
```

And here is the code causing the issue:

```
TopologyReader::ConstLinksIterator iter;
int num = 0;
for (iter = topologyReader->LinksBegin (); iter != topologyReader->LinksEnd(); iter++, num++)
  {
    std::istringstream fromName(iter->GetFromNodeName ());
    std::istringstream toName (iter->GetToNodeName ());
    iter->GetToNodeName();
    std::string w = "Weight";
    std::string weightAttr = (iter)->GetAttribute(w); // <- error
    /* snip */
  }
```

I think it might have to do with the fact that `GetAttribute(std::string)` is not a `const` function, according to the [documentation for TopologyReader::Link](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen-release/classns3_1_1_topology_reader_1_1_link.html), while the other functions, `GetFromNodeName(void)` and `GetToNodeName(void)` are declared as `const` functions. However, I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Edit: 
The function signatures are as shown (from the linked documentation):

```
std::string ns3::TopologyReader::Link::GetFromNodeName (void) const
std::string ns3::TopologyReader::Link::GetToNodeName (void) const
std::string ns3::TopologyReader::Link::GetAttribute (std::string name)
```

Comment: Ooops. I missed that, sorry. You may want to report this as a bug. It does look like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The obvious fix is to make `GetAttribute` be a const function. Its name suggests it *should* be const. It might not be in your power to change that code, though.

The alternative is to find some way of getting a non-const object to call the function on. Maybe you could declare `iter` as a `LinksIterator` instead of a `ConstLinksIterator`.

As a last resort, you could try using `const_cast` to tell the compiler that it's really safe to call a non-const method on a supposedly const object.

Comment: Since `LinksIterator` is not defined, I'll have to go with the `const_cast` method. How do I go about doing this? Do I need to cast the function as a `const`? (I'm quite new to C++)

Comment: @kibibyte `const_cast<TopologyReader::Link&>(*iter).GetAttribute ...`

Comment: Oh dear that's quite some horrid syntax. But it works now. Thanks!